# How is Virtual DOM updated?

Tags: reactjs, virtual-dom

Imagine that you've built an application with ReactJs containing a hundred elements. Let's say that in some time, the state of component A changes, and for the sake of simplicity we assume it has only one element and no child component.

My question is: how is Virtual DOM updated in response to the state change?

After a few hours of research, I found two contradictory opinions:

- The entire Virtual DOM is torn down; then it is rebuilt from scratch
- Only the changed elements are updated in the Virtual DOM.

Unfortunately, official documentation is not clear about this. So, can anybody give the correct answer? (please with supporting reference)

Answer (score 2):

**[Edit]** : Some parts are imcomplete here, think about reading the comment section !

---

React update a component when its state or a prop changes. It does a comparison between the previous JSX and the new one and re-render only the differences.

If the parent component has its state or a prop changed, it will be updated.
The child will not be refreshed unless a prop from the parent that is passed to it changes.

Note that the `useEffect` from the child is triggered first. Knowing that, If you do things that update the state in the child component, then it will be re-rendered everytime (Because the usEffect is triggered everytime if you don't set any dependencies).

[Test from Stackblitz - Child Effect is triggered first](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-child-effect-first?file=index.js)

[Article that made me notice it (I didn't know before this answer :D)](https://medium.com/better-programming/tips-for-using-reacts-useeffect-effectively-dfe6ae951421)

Here is how I understand things in React. To be short, the entire virtual DOM isn't rebuilt from scratch, it's not how JSX comparison works.

I don't have much sources about what I said, but here is [the explanation about jsx update](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#react-only-updates-whats-necessary) from the official documentation. Just that should be enough to eliminate the first point of your list.

Comment: So how do you interpret this answer from Dan Abramov: _rebuilding React tree...is not better for performance, but it’s usually good enough for most..._ 
(Please read the question he was answering too)
Ref: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/998329007119785985

Comment: @Hans Looks like I was wrong in my answer. I missunderstood the fact that the *It just replace what has changed* is about the real DOM. The virtual one (or the *tree of React components* as he says) is rebuilt completely. I also said something strange about the useEffect. I thought only the useEffect was triggered and not the render method, I guess it was also wrong. It IS triggered, which makes more sense, but if the rebuilt part is the same than what's in the previous virtual DOM then it does not changes in the view (the real DOM).

Comment: @HansI checked again the documentation I linked in my answer, and it talks about DOM, not *virtual* DOM. These two DOM misslead me, gotta be carecul now ! Thanks, I learned something today :)